# R DBI sql query result displayed in upper case but, then names seems to work as the query result was lowercase

Tags: r, r-dbi

I am learning on my own R for a short time.
I use DBI library to connect to a postgres DB containing a table, which has several fields taking 2 values: "false" and "true"
Let's call x one of the fields
I'd like to convert these character fields to integer namely 0 and 1, to do a logistic regression comprising these variables.
Calling df_tb the data frame retrieved by df_tb<-dbGetQuery(con,q)
strangely print(df_tb) displays uppercase fields FALSE and TRUE

I tried to use names function to convert these strings to integers ( 0 and 1 ) like this:

```
convert_to_int=c(0,1)
convert_to_int_str=c("FALSE","TRUE") 
names(convert_to_int)=convert_to_int_str
df_tb$x=convert_to_int[df_tb$x]
```

BUT R crashes executing : df_tb$x=convert_to_int[df_tb$x]
error messages says

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, x , value = c(`NA` = NA_real_,  :
  replacement has 34 rows, data has 430
Calls: $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

AND if I substitute this last command df_tb$x=convert_to_int[df_tb$x] by
`df_tb$x=convert_to_int[toupper(df_tb$x)]`
it works .

I've also tried to do the conversion without any uppercase letters, but that doesnt work neither

Does someone understand how it works ?
Thanks !

P.S.: If someone knows a simple way to convert on the whole dataframe true by integer 1 and false by 0, I am also greatly interested !!

Comment: Regarding the conversion, try `c(T,F) * 1`

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for your answer. It's a bit short, I don't actually understand what you mean suggesting to try c(T,F)*1 . Could you please write a slightly longer snippet for me to get it ? Thanks